# Question relating to a number theoretic function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Question;** For $a \geq 2$, Let $M(a) = $ the largest prime factor of $a$ i.e $M(6) = 3, M(9) = 3, M(69) = 23$ are there infinitely many $n$ so that 
$M(n-2) < M(n) < M(n+2)$ ?

One can show that for infinitely many $k$ we have $M(k-1) < M(k) < M(k+1)$ by considering the following lemma;

**Lemma;** If $M(y) > M(y-1),$ $\exists b \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ so that $M(y^{2^b} - 1) < M(y^{2^b}) < M(y^{2^b} +1)$

**Proof of Lemma;** If one has $M(y-1) < M(y) < M(y+1)$ then we are done, if not then we have $M(y^2-1) < M(y^2)$, If one has $M(y^2-1) < M(y^2) < M(y^2+1)$ then we are done if not then...

If the sequence of writing above ever terminates then we have the lemma; if not then one has that $\forall b$ $M(y^{2^b}) > M(y^{2^b}+1)$, i.e

$\forall b$ $M(y) > M(y^{2^b}+1)$; this is absurd (I will let you think about why).

I don't think the question above can rely on this trickery.

Comment: Twin primes' conjecture implies this: if $p$ and $p+2$ are prime then $M(p-2)<M(p)<M(p+2)$.

Comment: That conjecture is overkill, I "believe" my question is simpler.

Comment: Yes, of course, it was only a comment.

Comment: no worries all good here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint*:

For every $a\ge 2$,
$$M(2a)=M(a)$$

Comment: Yup that solves the problem thanks.

Comment: BTW, this idea  proves also $M(n-k)<M(n)<M(n+k)$ when $k$ is a power of two or three.

Comment: It can be extended to be proven for all $k \geq 1$